# How to read Excel data by column name in python using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlrd

I am trying to read the data of large excel file(almost 100000 row). 
I am using 'xlrd Module' in python to fetch the data from excel. 
I want to fetch data by column name(**Cascade,Schedule Name,Market**) instead of column number(**0,1,2**). 
Because my excel columns are not fixed. 
i know how to fetch data in case of fixed column.

[image]

here is the code by which i am fetching data from the excel for fixed column

```
import xlrd

file_location =r"C:\Users\Desktop\Vision.xlsx"
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet= workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
print(sheet.ncols,sheet.nrows,sheet.name,sheet.number)

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
   flag = 0
   for j in range(sheet.ncols):
      value=sheet.cell(i,j).value
```

If anyone has any solution of this, kindly let me know

Thanks

Comment: [Edit] your Question and give an examples of *"by column name instead of column number"*

Comment: i have made changes in my question.

Comment: can you show me how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Comment**: still not working when header of
>   `fieldnames = ['Cascade', 'Market', 'Schedule', 'Name]` and
>   `Sheet(['Cascade', 'Schedule', 'Name', 'Market'])` are equal.

Keep order of `fieldnames` in `col_idx`, was not my initial goal.

---

> **Question**:  I want to fetch data by column name

The following `OOP` solution will work:

```
class OrderedByName():
    """
    Privides a generator method, to iterate in Column Name ordered sequence
    Provides subscription, to get columns index by name. using class[name]
    """
    def __init__(self, sheet, fieldnames, row=0):
        """
        Create a OrderedDict {name:index} from 'fieldnames'
        :param sheet: The Worksheet to use
        :param fieldnames: Ordered List of Column Names
        :param row: Default Row Index for the Header Row
        """
        from collections import OrderedDict
        self.columns = OrderedDict().fromkeys(fieldnames, None)
        for n in range(sheet.ncols):
            self.columns[sheet.cell(row, n).value] = n

    @property
    def ncols(self):
        """
        Generator, equal usage as range(xlrd.ncols), 
          to iterate columns in ordered sequence
        :return: yield Column index
        """
        for idx in self.columns.values():
            yield idx

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        """
        Make class object subscriptable
        :param item: Column Name
        :return: Columns index
        """
        return self.columns[item]
```

> **Usage**:

```
# Worksheet Data
sheet([['Schedule', 'Cascade', 'Market'],
       ['SF05UB0', 'DO Macro Upgrade', 'Upper Cnetral Valley'],
       ['DE03HO0', 'DO Macro Upgrade', 'Toledo'],
       ['SF73XC4', 'DO Macro Upgrade', 'SF Bay']]
      )

# Instantiate with Ordered List of Column Names
# NOTE the different Order of Column Names
by_name = OrderedByName(sheet, ['Cascade', 'Market', 'Schedule'])

# Iterate all Rows and all Columns Ordered as instantiated
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    for col in by_name.ncols:
        value = sheet.cell(row, col).value
        print("cell({}).value == {}".format((row,col), value))
```

> > **Output**:
> >
> > ```
> > cell((0, 1)).value == Cascade
> > cell((0, 2)).value == Market
> > cell((0, 0)).value == Schedule
> > cell((1, 1)).value == DO Macro Upgrade
> > cell((1, 2)).value == Upper Cnetral Valley
> > cell((1, 0)).value == SF05UB0
> > cell((2, 1)).value == DO Macro Upgrade
> > cell((2, 2)).value == Toledo
> > cell((2, 0)).value == DE03HO0
> > cell((3, 1)).value == DO Macro Upgrade
> > cell((3, 2)).value == SF Bay
> > cell((3, 0)).value == SF73XC4
> > ```

---

> Get Index of **one** Column by Name
>
> ```
> print("cell{}.value == {}".format((1, by_name['Schedule']),
>                                     sheet.cell(1, by_name['Schedule']).value))
> #>>> cell(1, 0).value == SF05UB0
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***

Comment: thanks stovfl for your answer but you are only printing the column index in but i want to print all the data of corresponding of column name. can you show me how i should use these column index for fetch correspondin row data of it

Comment: @George.S: From your Question: *" i know how to fetch data in case of fixed column."*. [Edit] you Question and show a **not fixed** data table and **how you** do this using the `col_idx` list.

Comment: Actually " i know how to fetch data in case of fixed column." but problem is that in your code if i changed column header of my excel. it is print the column index in same order. so tell me how would my code knows that which header is residing in which column. i think i have cleared my point.

Comment: Thanks for update but it is still not working when header of fieldnames['Cascade', 'Market', 'Schedule', 'Name]  and  Sheet(['Cascade', 'Schedule', 'Name', 'Market']) are equal. it is not showing the exact position of column header.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you could also make use of [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/), which is a comprehensive data analysis library with built-in [excel I/O capabilities](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#excel-files).

```
import pandas as pd

file_location =r"C:\Users\esatnir\Desktop\Sprint Vision.xlsx"

# Read out first sheet of excel file and return as pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(file_location)

# Reduce dataframe to target columns (by filtering on column names)
df = df[['Cascade', 'Schedule Name', 'Market']]
```

where a quick view of the resulting dataframe `df` will show:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
   Cascade     Schedule Name                Market
0  SF05UB0  DO Macro Upgrade  Upper Central Valley
1  DE03HO0  DO Macro Upgrade                Toledo
2  SF73XC4  DO Macro Upgrade                SF Bay
```

Comment: Thank Xukrao for your answer but i do not know how to perform operation over excel data using pandas. so i am unable to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Your column names are in the first row of the spreadsheet, right? So read the first row and construct a mapping from names to column indices.

```
column_pos = [ (sheet.cell(0, i).value, i) for i in range(sheet.ncols) ]
colidx = dict(column_pos)
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
colidx = dict( (sheet.cell(0, i).value, i) for i in range(sheet.ncols) )
```

You can then use the index to interpret column names, for example:

```
print(sheet.cell(5, colidx["Schedule Name"]).value)
```

To get an entire column, you can use a list comprehension:

```
schedule = [ sheet.cell(i, colidx["Schedule Name"]).value for i in range(1, sheet.nrows) ]
```

If you really wanted to, you could create a wrapper for the `cell` function that handles the interpretation. But I think this is simple enough.

Comment: thanks Alexis for your answer. i want to fetch complete data of 'schedule name' instead of individual value. can you show me how ?

Comment: Done. (I assume row 0 contains the column names, so it's not included in the column values.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of pandas. Below is the sample code for identifying the columns and rows in an excel sheet.

```
import pandas as pd

file_location =r"Your_Excel_Path"

# Read out first sheet of excel file and return as pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(file_location)


total_rows=len(df.axes[0])
total_cols=len(df.axes[1])

# Print total number of rows in an excel sheet
print("Number of Rows: "+str(total_rows))

# Print total number of columns in an excel sheet
print("Number of Columns: "+str(total_cols))

# Print column names in an excel sheet
print(df.columns.ravel())
```

Now once you have the column data, you can convert it into a list of values.

Comment: As op commented on @Xukrao's answer that also utilize pandas, op don't know how to use pandas.